# how to cast this function type in typescript

Tags: typescript

I get confused about how to do this kind of type casting in TS. I am defining a class method that needs to be this type (https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/react-big-calendar/index.d.ts#L229)

and I am trying to do something like this...

```
  public onSelectSlot: Pick<BigCalendarProps<InterviewEvent>, 'onSelectSlot'> = (slot) => {
    this.setCreateDialog(true, slot.slots.slice(0, -1));
  }
```

but that is not working and I cannot figure out how to pull the function arg type out of that interface in the link. How can I go about doing this?

Comment: `(slot: { start: stringOrDate, end: stringOrDate, slots: Date[] | string[], action: 'select' | 'click' | 'doubleClick' }) => ...`?

Comment: right...but I want to avoid copying the type verbatim out of the @types module in case it changes in the future

Comment: Then ask the author of bigcalendar to define and export a named interface. Or define it yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `Pick`, that will not return the type of the proeprty but rather an object type with the picked properties.

You can use a type query to get the type of `onSelectSlot`.

```
  public onSelectSlot: BigCalendarProps<InterviewEvent>['onSelectSlot'] = (slot) => {
    this.setCreateDialog(true, slot.slots.slice(0, -1));
  }
```

Comment: cool, I've never seen it done like this before, Is this fairly unusual? I was about to make a PR to abstract out the arg type to an interface

Comment: I use it often .. Not sure how common it is. It is impractical to create distinct exported types for each callback you use (just the naming would be problematic) with type queries you can easily get the type of any property in a library ..

Answer (score 0):

Pick returns a set of properties

```
type Pick<T, K extends keyof T> = { [P in K]: T[P]; }
```

So if you want to get a propertie,you need to provide the key of propertie like this

```
public onSelectSlot: Pick<
    BigCalendarProps<InterviewEvent>,
    'onSelectSlot'
  >['onSelectSlot'] = slot => {};
```

Or you can define a type alias

```
type PickPropertie<T, K extends keyof T> = T[K];
```

and use it.

```
public onSelectSlot: PickPropertie<
    BigCalendarProps<InterviewEvent>,
    'onSelectSlot'
  > = slot => {};
```